# valign middle not working

Tags: html, css

Not sure why the `valign="middle"` not working here.  Can someone please help me out with what is missing here.

**HTML**

```
<table id="my_table"  style="width:100%;height:450px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
     <td width="5%" valign="middle">
        <div id="left_arrow" align="center">
            <img  src='./button/3.png' id='leftArrow' /
        </div>
     </td>
     <td width="60%" valign="middle" >
         <div id="left_table" >
           <div id="holder" >
             <img  src=".images/3.jpg" id="slideshow" />
           </div>
         </div>
     </td>
     <td width="5%"  valign="middle">
         <div id="right_arrow" align="center">
           <img  src='./button/2.png' id='rightArrow' />
         </div>
     </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: You mean `vertical-align` ?

Comment: `valign` was deprecated a long time ago.

Comment: yes..thats too not working

Comment: style="vertical-align:middle" but you really really really want to get away from inline styles.

Comment: I suggest you read on new web development techniques/standards as your markup is pretty outdated. We don't use tables for positioning elements or `<img>` tags for buttons or inline styles for elements.

Answer (score 5):

You want to take the inline styles out if possible, but here's the full solution.

```
<table id="my_table"  style="width:100%;height:450px" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
     <td width="5%" style="vertical-align:middle">
        <div id="left_arrow" align="center">
            <img  src='./button/3.png' id='leftArrow' />
        </div>
     </td>
     <td width="60%" style="vertical-align:middle">
         <div id="left_table" >
           <div id="holder" >
             <img  src=".images/3.jpg" id="slideshow" />
           </div>
         </div>
     </td>
     <td width="5%"  style="vertical-align:middle">
         <div id="right_arrow" align="center">
           <img  src='./button/2.png' id='rightArrow' />
         </div>
     </td> 
    </tr>
</table>
```

[Click here for live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Callie_/9vLta/1/)

Comment: Then there is some css overriding or your cells aren't tall enough to show the alignment properly.

Comment: HA! Thanks Callie, I was making the fiddle for it as you made the edit

Comment: yes I saw it working but when I copied the same code to my web directory..the middle td still appearing at the top .;(

Comment: do you have any styles that are effecting it?

Answer (score 3):

The valign attribute of  is not supported in HTML5. Use CSS instead.

CSS syntax: `<tr style="vertical-align:middle">`